# django render initial values in form with ModelMultipleChoiceField and CheckboxSelectMultiple() widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following form:

```
class TutorForm(SignupForm):
   subjects = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Subject.objects.all(),
                                          widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

I have a child form called `TutorUpdateForm`that inherits from `TutorForm` and it sets initial values in init method.

```
self.fields['subjects'].initial = current_user.subjects.all()
```

In my template however the values are not checked (in views the values are there, so setting initial values works). How can I enforce checked inputs in the template?

**EDIT (init code)**

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    current_user = None
    try:
        current_user = kwargs.pop('user')
    except Exception:
        pass
    super(TutorUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for field in _update_exclude:
        self.fields.pop(field)

    if current_user:
        self.fields['subjects'].initial = current_user.subjects.all()
```

Comment: please, include `__init__` method code in question, just to see where exactly you set `initial` ( check than you set property **after** `super` call ) and how see how you get `current_user`.

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking - what does it mean `"In my template the values are not checked"`. What happens, and what are you expecting to happen? What works in the views but doesn't in the template?

Comment: You can't change the initial value on a bound form. You can work with the value though, and if nothing has been selected, to change the value of the field (self.fields['subjects'].value) to current_user.subjects.all(). But then you'll lose the ability for a user to select no subjects at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should pass the initial values into the call to `super`, you can also set a default value for `dict.pop` rather than using try/except

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    current_user = kwargs.pop('user', None)

    initial = kwargs.get('initial', {})
    if current_user:
        initial.update({'subjects': current_user.subjects.all()})
    kwargs['initial'] = initial

    super(TutorUpdateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    for field in _update_exclude:
        self.fields.pop(field)
```

Here is a link to the documentation on [dynamic initial values for forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#dynamic-initial-values)